# data structure for sets of strings

Tags: c, optimization, data-structures

I was wondering if anyone could suggest a data structure for storing strings in two mutually exclusive sets. The operations would include adding and removing a string from a set, moving a string from one set to the other, and returning the number of strings in each set. I'm considering a trie, but I'm not sure about returning the number of strings in each set.

I would like to implement it in C.

Answer (score 0):

GLib has a hash table implementation you could use:
http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Hash-Tables.html

Comment: Would a hash be more efficient than a trie?

Comment: It depends.  Hash tables are more commonly known and implemented, so I'd start with that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two [priority queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) like [Self-balancing binary search trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) for each set.  You could also use a [treap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap).